# How to match time layout (m s)?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm not strong in regex pattern matching, but looking for some help. I'm trying to match this pattern using Regex.Match:

- 5m 26s
- 3m
- 42s
- 7m
- 4m 02s

I've checked the site and found some help but its not 100% what I'm looking (doesn't capture 3m & 7m or any with these type of values), all the other value match.

Based on my findings, I put together this pattern:

```
(m\s+)?(?:[1-5]?\ds)
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: are you trying to match it only, or do you want to convert it time a timespan or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern works for all your examples:

```
\b[0-5]?\d(?:m(?:\h[0-5]?\ds)?|s)\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/FdmNII/3

**Breakdown:**

```
\b                  # Word boundary.
[0-5]?\d            # A number between 00 and 59.
(?:                 # Start of 1st non-capturing group.
    m               # Matches the character `m` literally.
    (?:             # Start of 2nd non-capturing group.
        \h          # Any horizontal whitespace.
        [0-5]?\d    # A number between 00 and 59.
        s           # Matches the character `s` literally.
    )               # End of 2nd non-capturing group.
    ?               # Indicates that the previous group is optional.
    |               # Alternation (OR).
    s               # Matches the character `s` literally.
)                   # End of 1st non-capturing group.
\b                  # Word boundary.
```

If you also want to match something like `01m01s`, you can make the whitespace optional (i.e., `\h?` instead of `\h`).

Comment: Thanks!! this matched the values and got the correct amount of occurrences.